# Saveas function excel. with name from cell

Tags: excel, save-as, vba

I am trying to make the following code work for saving a file name in a certain format. I would like it to save in the folder the file was opened up in. the file would change it's name to a new month name. I have got most of it working, such as directory selection and filename and for it to save, however, if there is already a file with the same name or if someone selects no or cancel it gives an error. I have tried various ways of trying to get around it but now I'm at a loss. I have 2 codes they both are supposed to do the same thing, just variations.

```
Sub saving1()
' Saves the file under a new name based on the new month date.
    Dim NewFilename As String
    Dim tempnm
    Dim loc                                           ' variable for file location
    loc = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path               'loads the file location on the loc variable
    MsgBox loc
    ' creates the file name for saving includes the current path.
    NewFilename = loc + "\" + Range("NewFileName").Value & ".xlsm"
    'tempmm = Application.GetSaveAsFilename initialfilename

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFilename, FileFormat:=52
    'Application.DisplayAlert = False
    'On Error Resume Next    'to omit error when cancel is pressed
    '  MsgBox "Not saved"
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save

    'If Err.Number <> 1004 Then  'optional, to confirmed that is not saved
    '  MsgBox "Not saved"
    'End If
    ' On Error GoTo 0         'to return standard error operation

End Sub

Sub saving()
' Saves the file under a new name based on the new month date.
    Dim NewFilename As String
    Dim loc                                           ' variable for file location
    loc = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path               'loads the file location on the loc variable
    ' creates the file name for saving includes the current path.
    NewFilename = loc + "\" + Range("NewFileName").Value & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFilename, FileFormat:=52

End Sub
```

I also added message boxes to try see what it is doing during testing. I have also tried the Getsaveasfilename in order to give the user an option to choose his/her own filename and possibly folder. The file location will change once a year.

Answer (score 1):

If Your are looking at overwriting existing file, when there's already a file with same name try below.

```
NewFilename = loc + "\" + Range("NewFileName").Value & ".xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFilename, FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Ok thanks. it does work. i tried that before but i think i had them ( Application.displayalerts) in the wrong places. it works and there are no more errors.  i think it is better that there is simpler with no option of choosing the filename.